# Does Dijkstra works for non-negative or positive weights?

Tags: graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I know why Dijkstra doesn't work for negative weights but is 0 allowed as a weight?
I think that if two nodes have a 0 weight then the edge connecting those nodes can be eliminated and nodes be merged as one.
Is this right? or I'm missing something?

Comment: Note that *non-negative* and *positive* is the same, `0` is a positive value.

Comment: Well, I like to think '0' as unsigned and positive means strictly positive according to me.

Comment: That is okay but when others say *"Dijkstra works for positive weights"* then this means it also works for `0` because, for them, `0` is positive, just remember that.

Comment: Query answered well. Thanks. Big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the segment has weight zero, we can delete it, if all the segement between that pair of point are zero, you can delete them all, and merge two point to one!

Hope this post help you!

Comment: To extend the answer: The usual Dijkstra algorithm has no problems with zero-weighted edges. It will output the correct result too, even if not merging.